# Prevent screen lock on dimming/standby while using android app?

Tags: android, locking, screen

I'm developing an application and the last touch I need to put on it is preventing the screen to lock when the device goes into standby (screen off). The exact behavior as Google Navigation.

I'm wondering what, programatically I will have to use to keep this feature enable the entire time while using the app?

Comment: Follow the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: this may help http://www.androidsnippets.com/keep-the-screen-on

Answer (score 16):

writing the following code to your xml file will prevent the screen from locking

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

In the onCreate of your activity after the setContentView use this:

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Not tried it myself.

Comment: For posterity, this works well if your Activity never needs to change between normal and always-on screen states.