# Blank screen while returning from lock screen

Tags: android, lockscreen

I'm new to Android. I'm developing an application which will detect the frequency magnitude, phase and amplitude of sound using similarity method.

My application takes very long time to finish. The processing time always exceeds the lock screen time (the whole process usually takes 7-10 minutes).

The problem is :
When I want to return to my application (by unlocking the screen), sometimes my application goes blank. No elements are shown. There is no such messages saying "process bla bla bla has stopped unexpectedly". It's just blank.

I just want the process to run even when the screen is locked (no prevention of locking the screen just like this --> [Prevent screen lock on dimming/standby while using android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446299/prevent-screen-lock-on-dimming-standby-while-using-android-app)).

Can anyone tell me what happened here? and how to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: The processing work is done in AsyncTask?

Comment: From what you described, I suggest that you put your functionality into a service.  Then it can simply run in the background.  When the processing completes, you can display a notification, which, when clicked, will invoke some sort of UI with results.