# What are my options for always on NFC in my Android app?

Tags: android, nfc

I would like to create an app that listens for NFC tag scans for several hours.  A new NFC intent will normally happen every 2-3 minutes but sometimes 10-15 minutes apart.

The phone may be sitting in a users pocket while running so there is a possibility of accidental touch to the interface.

What options do I have to stop the phone going to sleep in between each NFC intent so that the user does not need to continually wake up the phone to scan a new NFC tag?

Rooting users phones to always enable NFC is not an option in this scenario.

The only thing I can think of is to create a blank screen with a custom unlock code/swipe so there is no accidental pushes... but this would use a lot of battery?

Answer (score 0):

Some phones will keep scanning for NFC even when the screen is locked, some won't.
There are security reasons (some tag payload can be forged to attack the NFC stack), and obvious battery saving reasons. The current GSMA recommendation in this area that NFC scanning be turned off as long as the screen is off. The impact of the battery will depend on the chip embedded in your phone, but the impact should be noticeable. Depending on your use case doing card emulation by the phone or UICC might be more efficient.

Comment: Yes I knew all of that.  The question was "What options do I have to stop the phone going to sleep in between each NFC intent so that the user does not need to continually wake up the phone to scan a new NFC tag?"

Comment: Maybe you should look at [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446299/prevent-screen-lock-on-dimming-standby-while-using-android-app). This would cause a lot of battery depletion because the screen backlight takes a lot of current compared to other things.